# Color not showing up in cycles, same nodes, two different objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, color

I am using the cycles render engine, because it is more versatile and many more attributes can be controlled with nodes.

The problem I have is that the same node structure don't show color on certain objects in the scene.

Picture (2) the nodes are used to color the streamlines and picture (1) the nodes are used to color the contours, but for some reason, the contours are just showing up as black/white/colorless objects

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have a vertex color named "Col" on both objects?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is "Col"